# Is there any way to do 'software raid' without losing data?I

Tags: windows, raid

I say software raid because that is a pretty tentative guess at what I actually want. I have two drives, both with stuff already on them which I want to combine. If they weren't full of stuff (data, not windows installation) I would use software raid to combine them into one big drive or make them into one partition. I could probably do this with some complicated reference system but really I just want to be able to keep saving things to X: without running out of space until both drives are full.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can move everything onto one drive, depending on what software/driver you're using it might be possible. As far as I know there exists no program that combines the filesystems from two drives however, at least one or the other of the two drives will lose it's data. Some programs won't even give you the option of saving the data on one drive. Also, if you do have a RAID that will allow you to save the data, you'll then have to run some special program to expand the filesystem to the extents of the drive.